# ATG Dust Project Setup and Steps

Tags: atg, atg-dust

I am new to ATG. I have an existing project resynchronized with MKS repository which is built using Ant Script.

I need to write a ATG Dust project to test my application. How should i do it. Can you please help me with the steps and some sample code.

Comment: Why `ATG Dust`? Its a project that has not been touched for nearly 4 years. Other frameworks, like Mockito, can be used to do the same sort of testing.

Comment: I want to use it. Help me if you can.